# Which SQL function can be used as alternative of FIRST() of Informatica in SQL?

Tags: sql, informatica

Hi I am trying to convert Informatica Aggregator transformation into SQL query and I am stuck in finding the alternative of **FIRST()** function of Informatica in SQL.I used below query:

```
Select emp.*,
       first_value(ename)over (order by empid) ename1,
       first_value(ehobby)over (order by empid) ehobby1
From emp;
```

This query is giving first row for all records but I want to group it by empid. Can anyone please suggest?

Comment: What dbms are you using (MySQL, Oracle, MS SQL Server, PostgreSQL, ...)? Please add as a tag because the answer is probably specific to that

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> This query is giving first row for all records but I want to group it by empid.

I would expect `empid` to be `distinct` in a table called `emp`.  But if you have multiple rows and you want the first value, then you need an ordering column.  Let me assume you have one.  In that case:

```
select emp.*,
       first_value(ename) over (partition by empid order by <ordering col>) as ename1,
       first_value(ehobby) over (partition by empid order by <ordering col>) as ehobby1
from emp;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Select empid,
       (select top 1 ISNULL(ename,'') from emp where ename=obj.ename order by empid) as ename1
       (select top 1 ISNULL(ehobby,'') from emp where ehobby=obj.ehobby order by empid) as ehobby1 
From emp as obj
group by obj.empid,obj.ename1,obj.ehobby1
```

I have tried above query please check this may be helpful and for Group by you have to select one column name
Apologies if something mistake
i am new in stackoverflow.

Comment: Thanks for suggestion Sir,
but i can't understand what you are trying to say can you just edit my post?